# Image not displayed from API call

Tags: reactjs, native

I have Screen A and Screen B. In screen A, I have an authentication which gives an API response with username, name, and avatar. I am able to pass the response from Screen A using this code and it appears successfully in Screen B:

```
.then ((res) => {   
    if(res.status == 200) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {email: this.state.email, username: res.data.user.username, name: res.data.user.name, avatar: res.data.user.avatar })            
        alert("Success!")       
    }
```

On screen B, I'm storing states as props:

```
export default class MainScreen extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        username: '', 
        email: '',
        name: '',
        avatar: '',
        User: this.props.navigation.state.params.username,
        Name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name,
        Avatar: this.props.navigation.state.params.avatar,
    }
}
```

To call and display the states (for username and name), I simply use the reference and it displays.

```
<TextInput value={this.state.User} username={this.state.username} changeName={this.changeName} editable={false} selectTextOnFocus={false}/>
```

However for image URI, the this.state.avatar call doesn't seem to work.

```
<Image source = {{uri: this.state.Avatar}}/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to this program.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width` and `height` to the image. Also, make sure the `uri` has absolute image url like `http://www.demo.com/image.jpg` and **NOT** something like `/image.jpg`

Comment: My API response has this: "avatar": "/system/users/avatars/000/000/034/medium/data?1534159740". Do I need to add the endpoint of the API to this?

Comment: That is not an image. If you are uploading image from device then you'll first have to convert it to base64 and then use it.

Comment: So i have converted an image to base 64, and uploaded it to an API. To present the image on my device, do I have to convert it to base 64 again?

Comment: No, just use <Image style={{width:100, height: 100}} source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64, base64codegoeshere' }} />

Comment: How would I make the call dynamic? Like for an API? Could we do: <Image style={{width:100, height: 100}} source={{ uri: 'data:image/png;base64', this.state.Avatar }} /> Would this work?